# Change folder permission to 777 using PHP temporarily

Tags: php, folder-permissions

I have a Video folder on my server which has 755 permission. The problem is: when someone goes to upload video file, it can't be upload into that folder because of permission error.

If I change the permission to 777, then Video can be uploaded. But I don't want to allow the folder permission to 777 for security reason.

Is there any way in PHP to temporary change the permission to 777 while uploading video?

Comment: Please give look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958602/still-dont-understand-file-upload-folder-permissions

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHP provides a function, [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for the task.

> Attempts to change the mode of the specified file to that given in mode.

You can put it in an `if` statement, and if it returns false, you can skip the upload file part.

---

The usage will be like

```
if( chmod($path, 0777) ) {
    // more code
    chmod($path, 0755);
}
else
    echo "Couldn't do it.";
```

As described in the [chmod function manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), the `$mode` must be in octal format - with leading zero, i.e `chmod($path, 0777)`

Comment: Wouldn't that if-clause already change the permissions to `0777`?

Comment: @AAGD Yes. But the question was: "_Is there any way in PHP to temporary change the permission to 777 while uploading video_"?

Comment: To check for file permission, use:
if ( substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($path)), -4) == '0777' ) { chmod($path, 0755); }

Answer (score 4):

There is a way (PHP provides `chmod` function) but since PHP is not the owner of the folder, you won't be able to change the permission. And I think you are solving the wrong problem. Add webserver and PHP in the same group and give 775 to the folder.

Comment: because PHP is obviously not in the group of the folder's owner :)

Comment: @MaximKrizhanovsky PHP user? Can you elaborate more please.

Comment: @ElberCM PHP can be run in several ways, including as part of the web server process, or as a CGI program. Most often than not PHP is under the same user as the web server. This is not necessary however. Check out [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7771662/797303)

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the config for the upload, like this:

```
$config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
$config['upload_path'] = $path;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: that has to do with codeigniter not what he's working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chmod()` function.

For more information, try [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: You cannot undo the file permissions that are changed by the script below. Proceed with extreme caution.

**Important**: this code should only be used if you remember to delete it immediately after use. As above, its use may put your site into an insecure state.

```
//replace dirname(__FILE__) with desired folder.
file_fix_directory(dirname(__FILE__));

function file_fix_directory($dir, $nomask = array('.', '..')) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
     // Try to make each directory world writable.
     if (@chmod($dir, 0777)) {
       echo "Made writable: " . $dir . "";
     }
  }
  if (is_dir($dir) && $handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if (!in_array($file, $nomask) && $file[0] != '.') {
        if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
          // Recurse into subdirectories
          file_fix_directory("$dir/$file", $nomask);
        }
        else {
          $filename = "$dir/$file";
            // Try to make each file world writable.
            if (@chmod($filename, 0666)) {
              echo "Made writable: " . $filename . "";
            }
        }
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);
  }

}
```

or you can use terminal for this

```
chmod -R 755 public_html/test
```